# Prevent CAB from showing on EditText text selection

Tags: android, android-edittext, textview, contextual-action-bar

I'm trying to prevent the standard Contextual Action Bar from showing upon selecting text in an EditText, while keeping the text selection functionality. (Cause I want to use custom views to copy, cut and paste)

I've browsed the web, and tried the following things, with no luck, and don't know what to do now.

- I tried overriding onLongClick() and returning false, which prevents the CAB from showing. but is also disables the text selection, so this is not a solution.
- I tried setting setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback(null), which has no effect at all.
- I tried setting setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback() with a custom ActionModeCallback, which contains the method onCreateActionMode(), in which I return false to "abort the mode", but this unfortunately also disables the text selection functionality.
- I even tried extending EditText and overriding startActionMode() and pass null to the super, like below, but which just made it crash.

.

```
@Override
public ActionMode startActionMode(ActionMode.Callback callback) {
    return super.startActionMode(null);
}
```

With the following error

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView$ActionModeCallbackWrapper.onCreateActionMode(PhoneWindow.java:3011)
            at com.android.internal.app.ActionBarImpl$ActionModeImpl.dispatchOnCreate(ActionBarImpl.java:909)
            at com.android.internal.app.ActionBarImpl.startActionMode(ActionBarImpl.java:453)
            at android.app.Activity.onWindowStartingActionMode(Activity.java:5005)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS$WindowCallbackWrapper.onWindowStartingActionMode(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:349)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.startActionMode(PhoneWindow.java:2636)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.startActionModeForChild(PhoneWindow.java:2623)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.startActionModeForChild(ViewGroup.java:665)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.startActionModeForChild(ViewGroup.java:665)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.startActionModeForChild(ViewGroup.java:665)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.startActionModeForChild(ViewGroup.java:665)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.startActionModeForChild(ViewGroup.java:665)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.startActionModeForChild(ViewGroup.java:665)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.startActionModeForChild(ViewGroup.java:665)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.startActionModeForChild(ViewGroup.java:665)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.startActionModeForChild(ViewGroup.java:665)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.startActionModeForChild(ViewGroup.java:665)
            at android.view.View.startActionMode(View.java:4543)
            at com.harteg.homenotes.EditTextFormat.startActionMode(EditTextFormat.java:480)
            at android.widget.Editor.startSelectionActionMode(Editor.java:1551)
            at android.widget.Editor.performLongClick(Editor.java:859)
            at android.widget.TextView.performLongClick(TextView.java:8362)
            at android.view.View$CheckForLongPress.run(View.java:18425)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5081)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:607)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: exccelent question. I try to do something similar, because of an android bug with text selection. E.g. whenever you put an edittext inside a dialog, and longpress the edittext, the app crashes. Have you found anything so far?

Comment: @Entreco No, sadly not..